# Find string in array Powershell V2.0

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-5.0

I have trouble with a script which is working in PowerShell V5.0 but doesn't work in V2.0.

I need to compare two columns in two CSV files and edit one value in one CSV if it exists in both files.

This is an example with the problem. `$a` is renamed in V5.0 to 1X and in V2.0 it is still 1. I try to use `Compare` but that doesn't solve the problem for me. Upgrading to V5.0 on that specific machine is unfortunately not an option. Any advice you could offer would be greatly appreciated.

```
# create examples
$a = @()
$itema = New-Object PSObject
$itema | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name 'ID' -Value '1'
$a += $itema

$b = @()
$itemb = New-Object PSObject
$itemb | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name 'ID' -Value '1'
$b += $itemb

# problem
foreach ($value in $a) {
    $ID = $value.ID
    if ($b.ID -contains $ID) {$value.ID = $ID + "X"}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Powershell 2.0 does not support the feature that lets you select multiple properties of the same name from the objects in an array.

In later Powershell versions, `$b.ID` will give you an array of all `ID` values from the objects in `$b`. In Powershell 2.0 this does not happen, `$.ID` is `$null`, because there is no `ID` property on the array itself.

You can extract the array like this:

```
$known_IDs = $b | ForEach-Object { $_.ID }
```

After that, this works in PowerShell 2.0:

```
foreach ($item_a in $a) {
    if ($known_IDs -contains $item_a.ID) {
        $item_a.ID += "X"
    }
}
```

Or, as a pipeline:

```
$a | Where-Object { $known_IDs -contains $_.ID } | ForEach-Object { $_.ID += "X" }
```

Comment: This is the fastest solution.

Answer (score 2):

PowerShell v2 doesn't support [member enumeration](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2012/06/13/new-v3-language-features/), which is what you're using here:

```
$b.ID -contains $ID
```

The feature was introduced with PowerShell v3.

In PowerShell v2 `$b.ID` tries to expand a property `ID` of the *array* `$b`, which produces an empty result because the array object doesn't have such a property.

In PowerShell v3 and newer `$b.ID` tries to expand a property `ID` on the *elements* of the array `$b` (if the array object itself doesn't have that property).

To make your code compatible to PowerShell v2 change this:

```
if ($b.ID -contains $ID) {$value.ID = $ID + "X"}
```

into this:

```
if (@($b | Select-Object -Expand ID) -contains $ID) {$value.ID = $ID + "X"}
```

---

**Addendum:**

For performance reasons it would make sense to expand the ID list just once outside the loop and store it in a separate variable

```
$id_list = @($b | Select-Object -Expand ID)
```

and then use that variable in the comparison:

```
if ($id_list -contains $ID) {$value.ID = $ID + "X"}
```

If you're *really* pressed for performance I'd recommend creating a hashtable from the IDs

```
$id_list = @{}
foreach ($e in $b) {
    $id_list[$e.ID] = $true
}
```

and do the comparison like this:

```
if ($id_list.ContainsKey($ID)) {$value.ID = $ID + "X"}
```

Hashtable lookups provide better performance than `-contains` operations because the former does an index lookup while the latter does a linear search on an array.